# Search not done unless complete line typed in edit text

Tags: android, listview, search, parse-platform

I have a new search activity which has a editext to enter search query and search button to search entered query in `EditText`

The searched items are displayed in a `ListView` in the search activity

Now the problem is I have a `ListView` from where the user searches what is needed

Let us suppose that this list view has 100 listitems with all named
 :

1. **test heading 1,**
2. **test heading 2,**
3. **test heading 3 ,**
4. **test heading 4,**

   **and so on till test heading 100**

Now in the search activity in editext if I enter " **test** " and press the search button it should display all the list since every list item heading contains test in its heading  but i get nothing

I had to enter the whole heading for the search to complete like " **test heading 1** " and the matching heading is displayed in the list

How can i make the search more better that if i enter " **test** " in edittext and press the search button it should display all the items containg test word in its heading

[image: this is the original list view which contains all the test headings]

[image: this is the search activity where i hae to enter the complete and correct list heading in order to perform search]

**for now i am using parse.com to retrieve data into listview(and sad thar parse.com is closing) and i am in the progress of migrating my database to m6 own server**

**the code i have tried**

**search activity**

```
public class SearchActivity extends Activity
 {

protected  EditText searchedittext;
 Button searchButton;
List<ParseObject> ob;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState )
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search_layout);

    searchedittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_layoutEditText);

    final ListView searchedlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.searchlist);
    searchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchlayoutbtn);

    searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            String seaechedit = searchedittext.getText().toString();

            if(seaechedit.isEmpty()){

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SearchActivity.this);
                builder.setMessage("PLEASE ENTER SOME SEARCH QUERY")
                       .setTitle("EMPTY SEARCH") 
                       .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);

                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();

            }
            else{
                setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
                // InterActivity is the class name in parse database where listview retrives it data from
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                    "InterActivity");

                query.whereEqualTo("listheading", seaechedit);
                query.orderByAscending("_created_at");
                query.setLimit(200);

                query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

                        @Override
                        public void done(List<ParseObject> p1, ParseException e)
                        {
                            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

                            if(e == null){

                                ob = p1;

                                String [] searchHeadings = new String[ob.size()];

                                int i = 0;

                                     // listheading is the coloumn name in parse database
                                      for(ParseObject heading : ob){ searchHeadings[i] = (String) heading.get("listheading");
                                i++;

                                }

                                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( SearchActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, searchHeadings );
                                searchedlist.setAdapter(adapter);


                            }else{

                                Log.e("searchactivity", e.getMessage()); 
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SearchActivity.this); 
                                builder.setMessage(e.getMessage()) 
                                       .setTitle("Nothing found")
                                       .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null); 
                                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                                dialog.show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
            }


        }

    });

}



 }
```

**aynctask of activity of rhe list in 1st image**

```
private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();


        dialog = new SpotsDialog(InterActivity.this, R.style.Custom);

        dialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create the array
        codelist = new ArrayList<CodeList>();
        try {
            // Locate the class table named "Country" in Parse.com
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                "InterActivity");
            // Locate the column named "ranknum" in Parse.com and order list
            // by ascending
            query.orderByAscending("_created_at");
            query.setLimit(limit);
            ob = query.find();
            for (ParseObject inter : ob) {




                map.setDescription((String) inter.get("subheading"));
                map.setIntroduction((String) inter.get("intro"));


                codelist.add(map);
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml


        listview = (SwipeMenuListView) findViewById(R.id.inter_layoutListView);
        // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
        adapter = new FinalAdapter(InterActivity.this,
                                      codelist);


        // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);


        listview.setOnItemClickListener(InterActivity.this);


        dialog.dismiss();





}


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> p1, View view, int position, long p4)
{

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    CodeList codes = (CodeList) adapter.getItem(position);


    try{

        Intent intent = new Intent(InterActivity.this, SingleItemView.class);

        String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(codes);


        intent.putExtra("selected item", jsonString);





        intent.putExtra("subheading",
                        (codelist.get(position).getDescription()));



        intent.putExtra("intro",
                        (codelist.get(position).getIntroduction()));



        // Start SingleItemView Class
        //   startActivity(intent);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

    }catch(JsonProcessingException e){
        //something went w3ong
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using  `whereEqualTo()` **it  requires a particular key's value to be equal to the provided value.**

```
query.whereEqualTo("listheading", seaechedit);
```

replace it with **it  find string values that contain a provided string.**

```
query.whereContains("listheading", seaechedit);
```

### see [whereContains Function](https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/ParseQuery.html#whereContains(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String))

Comment: I'll try it and let you know,thnx

Comment: Thank you very much, didnt know about that

Comment: Welcome @user5894647 happy coding

Comment: bro i had a new problem, how do i set on item clicklitener for search activity as i did in main list activity as shown in 1st imageto open corresponding singleitemview,i posted my 1st image's ac5ivity in my question,pls have a look and help me

Comment: i even triedcimplementing onitemclicklistener for searchactivity and paste the obnitemclick method from main list activity but item click does not open singleitem class

Comment: if have another question please ask separately

Comment: you mean i post the same thing as another question.?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104394/discussion-between-nj-nilesh-j-and-user5894647).

Comment: i  have posted a new question of my problem in detail http://stackoverflow.com/q/35601890/5894647,,pls have a look and help me