# Onitemclicklistener not working as same in search activity as it works in main activity

Tags: android, listview, search, parse-platform, onitemclicklistener

I have a main activity that displays a list retrived from parse.com( i  know that parse.comis being closed and i am in the progress on migrating to my own server)[image]

Now I have everything working in this activity like onitemclick etc,.
But I have another activity i.e. search activity that searches whether a list item searched by user is present in main activity's list
This too works fine but when the search results are shown the user should be able to click on desired results and be directed to singleitem class as they would be if they were in main activity

I am not able to implement this since when i click on search results nothing happens
I tried implemmenting onitemclicklistener for search activity as i did in main activity but no change

My code

**aynctask of mainactivity of rhe list inimage and its onitem clicklistener**

```
private class RemoteDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();


        dialog = new SpotsDialog(InterActivity.this, R.style.Custom);

        dialog.show();
    }


    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create the array
        codelist = new ArrayList<CodeList>();
        try {
            // Locate the class table named "Country" in Parse.com
            ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                "InterActivity");
            // Locate the column named "ranknum" in Parse.com and order list
            // by ascending
            query.orderByAscending("_created_at");
            query.setLimit(limit);
            ob = query.find();
            for (ParseObject inter : ob) {




                map.setDescription((String) inter.get("subheading"));
                map.setIntroduction((String) inter.get("intro"));


                codelist.add(map);
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml


        listview = (SwipeMenuListView) findViewById(R.id.inter_layoutListView);
        // Pass the results into ListViewAdapter.java
        adapter = new FinalAdapter(InterActivity.this,
                                      codelist);


        // Binds the Adapter to the ListView
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);


        listview.setOnItemClickListener(InterActivity.this);


        dialog.dismiss();





}


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> p1, View view, int position, long p4)
{

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    CodeList codes = (CodeList) adapter.getItem(position);


    try{

        Intent intent = new Intent(InterActivity.this, SingleItemView.class);

        String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(codes);


        intent.putExtra("selected item", jsonString);





        intent.putExtra("subheading",
                        (codelist.get(position).getDescription()));



        intent.putExtra("intro",
                        (codelist.get(position).getIntroduction()));



        // Start SingleItemView Class
        //   startActivity(intent);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

    }catch(JsonProcessingException e){
        //something went w3ong
    }
}
```

**search activity**

```
public class SearchActivity extends Activity
```

implements OnItemClickListener
     {

```
protected  EditText searchedittext;
 Button searchButton;
List<ParseObject> ob;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState )
{
    // TODO: Implement this method
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.search_layout);

    searchedittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_layoutEditText);

    final ListView searchedlist = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.searchlist);
    searchButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.searchlayoutbtn);

    searchButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            String seaechedit = searchedittext.getText().toString();

            if(seaechedit.isEmpty()){

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SearchActivity.this);
                builder.setMessage("PLEASE ENTER SOME SEARCH QUERY")
                       .setTitle("EMPTY SEARCH") 
                       .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);

                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                dialog.show();

            }
            else{
                setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
                // InterActivity is the class name in parse database where listview retrives it data from
                ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>(
                    "InterActivity");

                query.whereContains("listheading", seaechedit);
                query.orderByAscending("_created_at");
                query.setLimit(200);

                query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {

                        @Override
                        public void done(List<ParseObject> p1, ParseException e)
                        {
                            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

                            if(e == null){

                                ob = p1;

                                String [] searchHeadings = new String[ob.size()];

                                int i = 0;

                                     // listheading is the coloumn name in parse database
                                      for(ParseObject heading : ob){ searchHeadings[i] = (String) heading.get("listheading");
                                i++;

                                }

                                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>( SearchActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, searchHeadings );
                                searchedlist.setAdapter(adapter);
```

searchedlist.setOnItemClickListener(this);

```
                            }else{

                                Log.e("searchactivity", e.getMessage()); 
                                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SearchActivity.this); 
                                builder.setMessage(e.getMessage()) 
                                       .setTitle("Nothing found")
                                       .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null); 
                                AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                                dialog.show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
            }


        }

    });

}


@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> p1, View view, int position, long p4)
{

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    CodeList codes = (CodeList) adapter.getItem(position);


    try{

        Intent intent = new Intent(InterActivity.this, SingleItemView.class);

        String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(codes);


        intent.putExtra("selected item", jsonString);





        intent.putExtra("subheading",
                        (codelist.get(position).getDescription()));



        intent.putExtra("intro",
                        (codelist.get(position).getIntroduction()));



        // Start SingleItemView Class
        //   startActivity(intent);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

    }catch(JsonProcessingException e){
        //something went w3ong
    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the mistake

Forgot to execute RemoteDataTask in search activity as done in main activit